# Is there a function in Pandas or Numpy to populate dataframe from a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to create a row for each number in Volume for each make and company.
Not sure if there is a way, my googling skills did not find any solutions...

I have tried som for loops, but without success.

Here is a table as example.

```
0   Ford    2000    CompanyX
1   Volvo   3000    CompanyX
2   Mazda   2400    CompanyX
3   Fiat    1000    CompanyX
4   Ford    2000    CompanyY
5   Volvo   3000    CompanyY
6   Mazda   2400    CompanyY
7   Fiat    1000    CompanyY
```

End result should then be 16800 rows where each row should be e.g.

```
0 Ford 1 CompanyX
1 Ford 1 CompanyX
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "apply" method with "lambda" :

**Solution 1:**

Run on rows, one by one and for each row, pass the volume to a specific function and return an array with ones.

```
from datetime import timedelta  
def check(volume):  
    return [1 for i in range(volume)]

df1['Volume'] = df1.apply(lambda row: check(row['Volume']),axis=1)

df1 = df1.explode('Volume')

df1
```

**Solution 2:**

Apply only on the "Volume" column, so for each value, get the ones as an array.

```
df1['Volume'] = df1['Volume'].apply(lambda col: [1 for i in range(col)])
df1 = df1.explode('Volume')
df1
```

**Result :**

```
User ID Make    Volume  Company
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
0   1   Ford    1   CompanyX
1   2   Volvo   1   CompanyY
1   2   Volvo   1   CompanyY
1   2   Volvo   1   CompanyY
1   2   Volvo   1   CompanyY
1   2   Volvo   1   CompanyY
```

I also compared the performance between 3 methods. The 3rd method is rafaelc's answer above.

[image]

Comment: I like the way you think ;p so I've +1ed, but just as a constructive comment: usually working with lists inside cells and `explode` are costly methods both in space and time - takes up lots of memory and takes lots of time to take. For repeating stuff or creating long sequences, prefer `np.repeat` and similar methods as a general rule ! They use some compiled C code underneath to allocate arrays in a dynamic and faster way than with pure python ;}

Comment: Thank you @rafaelc. In fact, I am trying to understand the faster methods and for that reason, I am comparing the performance. I was looking for something faster than the "range" method, especially using numpy. "explode" is a new method for me, and I don't know the performance impact yet. I will check it more and will try np.repeat :)

Comment: @rafaelc, I added your code to the comparison above and indeed it is better than what I did :)

Comment: One more tip! Instead of manually writing the times, use the `%timeit` magic command on jupyter notebook to  get timing on a single line ;p and `%%timeit` on multiple lines! try it out, will make your life easier

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you may use `loc`+`df.index.repeat`, and then just set your `vol` to 1.

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.vol)]
df['vol'] = 1
```